# Extract data from User defined type via cx_Oracle

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle, user-defined-types

I am trying to extract data from User defined type (UDT) via cx_Oracle. Here is the UDT structure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE graphic_component AS OBJECT (
   type             NUMBER(6),
   source_type      NUMBER(4),
   meta_type_id     VARCHAR2(50 CHAR),
   name             VARCHAR2(100 CHAR),
   extension_info   VARCHAR2(500 CHAR),
   symbology_tokens VARCHAR2(2000 CHAR)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE graphic_component_array AS
      VARRAY (10000) OF graphic_component;
```

Here is an example using Python:

```
>>>insert = cursor.execute("SELECT COMPLEX FROM GRAPHIC WHERE ID=48662511087446403855368")
>>>complex = insert.fetchall()
[(<cx_Oracle.Object SCHEMA.GRAPHIC_COMPONENT_ARRAY at 0x33d71d0>,)]
>>>dir(complex)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'append', 'aslist', 'copy', 'delete', 'exists', 'extend', 'first', 'getelement', 'last', 'next', 'prev', 'setelement', 'size', 'trim', 'type']
>>>complex.first()
0
```

You can see there is a good user defined type but I can't extract data from this or any other UDT. I tried to check all properties of the object and I found methods first(), getelement() and last(). But these functions returns only 0.

Is there any way how to extract data from UDT via cx_Oracle or is there any other option how to get data.

**UPDATE**

```
<cx_Oracle.Object GRAPHIC_COMPONENT_ARRAY at 0x26c9f10>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/petr.silhak/PycharmProjects/migration-to-postgresql/test_parsing.py", line 34, in <module>
    print(ObjectRepr(complex[0][0]))
  File "C:/Users/petr.silhak/PycharmProjects/migration-to-postgresql/test_parsing.py", line 9, in ObjectRepr
    value = ObjectRepr(value)
  File "C:/Users/petr.silhak/PycharmProjects/migration-to-postgresql/test_parsing.py", line 14, in ObjectRepr
    value = getattr(obj, attr.name)
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1014: conversion between Oracle type 2010 and native type 3000 is not implemented
```

Comment: Check out the examples in https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/tree/master/samples/tutorial

Comment: Thanks Christopher I checked the examples but I didn't find example of querying UDT. The code of @wolfrevokcats works but for another UDT not for the specific one. There was some problem with Oracle type conversion.

Comment: I guess that should be another question.

Comment: Look for the SDO example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3949347) is the piece of code that handles complex types in cx_Oracle.
Excerpt:

```
def ObjectRepr(obj):
    if obj.type.iscollection:
        returnValue = []
        for value in obj.aslist():
            if isinstance(value, cx_Oracle.Object):
                value = ObjectRepr(value)
            returnValue.append(value)
    else:
        returnValue = {}
        for attr in obj.type.attributes:
            value = getattr(obj, attr.name)
            if value is None:
                continue
            elif isinstance(value, cx_Oracle.Object):
                value = ObjectRepr(value)
            returnValue[attr.name] = value
    return returnValue
```

You use it like `ObjectRepr(complex[0][0])`,  if `len(complex)>0`, of course

Comment: Thanks a lot. it works on other UDT but not for the specific one I send. I updated answer. There is an error, which is strange because how I said it works for another UDT which has almost the same structure.